# How can I apply jquery selector to only visible checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, visibility

I have the following code that checks all checkboxes in a html table column

```
$('.selectAll').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

which works great except in certain cases some of the rows of the table are hidden so **in those use cases I DONT want those hidden checkboxes to be checked.**

How can I include a visibility check as well to the above code so it only checks visible checkboxes.  So basically I want to add a visible addition to this line:

```
 $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) with `input` like

```
$('input:visible[type=checkbox][value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']')
```

You can use `.filter()` also, Heres an example

```
$('.selectAll').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function(){
        return  $(this).is(':visible') && $(this).val() == id;
    }).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to check if the thing i an clicking is visible (as clearly it is because i am clicking it) I am to put the filter on this line $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']').prop('checked', true);

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
 $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']:visible').prop('checked', true);
```

and

```
 $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']:visible').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better be careful with ":visible" , because elements with "visibility: hidden" or "opacity: 0" are still considered visible, since they still take space in the page layout.

If you are sure this wont be a problem in your case, then Milind's suggestion is correct.

```
 $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']:visible').prop('checked', true);
```